# Task.Factory.StartNew(someMethod(withParam)).continueWith(sameMethod(differentParam)).Wait()

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

What is the correct syntax for parallelizing the following code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
            doOne(SelectedTask.option1)
           .ContinueWith(
            task => 
            doOne(SelectedTask.option1)).Wait()
   ); 
}
```

Same method with `enum` "selectedTask" to decide which code to execute :

```
static enum SelectedTask
{
    option1,
    option2
}

static void doOne(SelectedTask Lunch)
{ 
    switch (lunch)
    {
        case SelectedTask.option1:
            Console.WriteLine("option1");
            break;
        case SelectedTask.option2:
            Console.WriteLine("option2");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you want your `doOne` calls to occur concurrently?  Then you can just start them straight from the task factory:

```
// Start two concurrent tasks
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doOne(SelectedTask.option1));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doOne(SelectedTask.option2));

// Block the current thread until all tasks complete
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

Do you want your `doOne` calls to occur sequentially?  Then you can chain them using `ContinueWith`:

```
// Start a chain of tasks
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doOne(SelectedTask.option1));
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t => doOne(SelectedTask.option2));

// Block the current thread until the last task completes
task2.Wait();
```

The code in the title of your post (with a couple of fixes) is essentially performing the exact same function as my sequential task chain above:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doOne(SelectedTask.option1))
            .ContinueWith(t => doOne(SelectedTask.option2))
            .Wait();
```

**Answer to your question below.**

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to run a task for a variable list of `SelectedTasks` in parallel:

```
List<SelectedTask> selectedTaskOptions = new List<SelectedTask>()
{
    SelectedTask.option1,
    SelectedTask.option2,
    SelectedTask.option3,
    SelectedTask.option4,
    SelectedTask.option5
};

RunAllSelectedTaskOptions(selectedTaskOptions);
```

`RunAllSelectedTaskOptions` to accept and run a list of `SelectedTasks`:

```
public void RunAllSelectedTaskOptions(List<SelectedTask> selectedTaskOptions)
{
    List<Task> createdTasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach(var taskOption in selectedTaskOptions)
    {
        createdTasks.Add(Task.Factory.CreateNew(() => doOne(taskOption)));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(createdTasks);
}
```

Another way of implementing `RunAllSelectedTaskOptions` would be to use `Parallel.ForEach`, which will execute in parallel and will block until the slowest/last iteration has completed:

```
public void RunAllSelectedTaskOptions(List<SelectedTask> selectedTaskOptions)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(selectedTaskOptions, taskOption => doOne(taskOption));
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot, It(last example in answer) Also Accepts Parameters passed to `doOne()`, only...not via parallel execution but in One Elegant Line of Code, one last Question if i may ask, the only option to run tasks in parallel would be the first example? which declares each task with separated declaration, and then perform `Task.WaitAll()` On all, do you know about an elegant way to take a class that will have 5-10 methods like (option1,2 3 4...) and execute the bunch, future is having at least 10 of them (doesn't matter will be in one class or not (could be if we choose) could it be done?

Comment: looks great gonna check on that !! (you knew i am using enum as parameter kinda selector..)

Comment: sorry i forgot i wrote all the code in my post ... including the enum(:

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about parallelizing the two `doOne` calls?

If so, then you will need to do something like this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doOne(SelectedTask.option1));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doOne(SelectedTask.option2));
var taskList = new List<Task>{task1, task2};
Task.WaitAll(taskList);
```

*The above code is fairly accurate but the syntax has not been validated.

Comment: so i guess the `Task.Factory` is limited to empty(no parameters) methods , and using a List<tasks> will behave same way as `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, only differece is with code in your answer it allows you to pass parameters to method ?

Comment: only thing you didn't get accurate is ToArray() on your WaitAll ...parameter could only be array rather than list

Comment: @LoneXcoder You can pass parameters either through a closure (but you should do this cautiously) or via the generic version of StartNew's action: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456.aspx